# Is it always a good idea to import very specifically in Python?

Tags: python, django

This is pretty much Python, but asking from a Django user.

Suppose this is how Django apps are layout:

> Webclient
>
> - apps
>
>   - myapp#1
>
>     - library
>
>       - library.py
>   - myapp#2
>
>     - views.py
>   - myapp#3

If I am working with views.py, and I want to import library.py, which one seems better?

```
from webclient.apps.myapp.library import LibraryClass
from webclient.apps.myapp.library.library import LibraryClass
```

I am using PyCharm, and either way doesn't complain about "unresolved references". 
Is it better to import very speifically. Is second import method more likely to avoid name collison, if possible at all (say /library/ has several .py files)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always import names from where they're defined. That way if `webclient.apps.myapp.library` should stop importing `LibraryClass` one day, you won't break the other imports.

Comment: Thank you. Bear with me. "where they're defined" means the first or the second?

Comment: If `LibraryClass` is defined in `webclient.apps.myapp.library.library`, then from there.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up to Ignacio's answer, you should look at the documentation of the libraries you are using, to see where it suggests you import things. It may be that although `LibraryClass` is defined in `webclient.apps.myapp.library.library`, it is documented as being in `webclient.apps.myapp.library`, so at some point, it the definition might be moved there, or `webclient.apps.myapp.library.oldversion`, but still accessible from `webclient.apps.myapp.library`.