# Is it a good idea to import packages from other packages in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

Suppose there is some well-known (third-party) Python package `a`, which depends on another well-known package `b` (e.g. `imageio` and `numpy`, respectively). Both are available through pip.

Now suppose my own code explicitly uses both `a` and `b`. Package versions are fixed in my `requirements.txt`.

I see a few options for importing and using these packages, as described below. To me Options 2 and 3 look the cleanest, as they appear to reduce the number of dependencies that I need to manage *explicitly*.

Is there a preferred way of importing these packages, from the dependency management point-of-view? Or is it just a matter of style?

Option 1:

```
import a
import b
...
a.something()
b.something_else()
...
```

Option 2:

```
import a  # which imports b
...
a.something()
a.b.something_else()
...
```

Option 3:

```
import a
from a import b
...
a.something()
b.something_else()
...
```

p.s. The following questions seem related but do not provide an answer: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43823968/4720018), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12229580/4720018), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25799347/4720018), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8958502/4720018)

Comment: I choose option 1 as I am not certain when library `a` will use lib `c` in place of `b` in future

Comment: If you don't need to complicate things, don't. Just do whatever seems to be instinctive (which I'm fairly certain is Option 1 for most people).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always manage your direct dependencies *explicitly* and not depend on internal implementation details of 3rd party packages. Those may change with future updates (unless a 3rd party package explicitly states that it exposes some particular package) and your code will break. If you depend on package `b`, put it into your requirements.txt *and* `import b` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A maxim in the Python community is: "flat is better than nested."  For this reason, I dislike Option 2.  It is less readable.  Also, if package A should ever change the way that it organizes its namespace, Option 2 could break.

Options 1 and 3 read identically within the main body of the code, so I have trouble choosing between them.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't option 3 a variation of 2, as it gets `b` from `a`?

Comment: It's true that options 2 and 3 both get `b` from `a`.  But the nested function call is less readable than the flat one.  Also, user "anuragal" pointed out that  Option 3 suffers from the same import dependency that I identified in Option 2.  Now I feel comfortable choosing Option 1 over the other two choices.